# mPDF: image in CSS

Tags: php, css, image, mpdf

I'm using mPDF to generate PDF's on my website.
In my CSS I use to have a image as background:

```
.page{
        height:297mm; 
        width:210mm;
        background:url(../bookletFiles/exam_header.png) no-repeat scroll;
        padding:400px 1.6cm 1.7cm 1.6cm;
}
```

This has been working for a long time. But lately I noticed that, when I declare $mPDF->debug to true, I receive the following error:

```
<B>mPDF error: </B>IMAGE Error (http://topografieindeklas.nl/wp-content/themes/topografieindeklas/bookletFiles/exam_header.png): Could not find image file
```

Strangley, when I remove the CSS declaration and use the exact same image in  tag's, it is displayed. 
I already tried to regenerate the .png file, replace it with a .jpg file but this hasn't had any result.

The only thing I can image that has changed lately, is an upgrade from PHP 5.3 to 5.4 The allow_url_fopen settings is set to true though.

Does anyone has any thoughts on why this image won't load through CSS and how that could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the view of your pdf file.

```
<?php $dir= $this->webroot."img/cake.icon.png"; ?>
<?php echo $dir; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $dir; ?>">
```

Comment: as already specified by the author, this works fine. It is however not a solution; since the layout will be different when display a background-image as a regular image instead